# Duende Identity Server v6 throwing "WindowsCryptographicException: Key does not exist"

Tags: c#, identityserver4, ef-core-6.0, duende-identity-server, duende

I'm upgrading from identity server 4 to duende identity server 6.

When running locally I can reference a key up on Azure Key Vault no problems via "DefaultAzureCredential" and it sets it correctly.

BUT :(

Then the site runs (site and identity server all running as one) and I login it throws an exception "WindowsCryptographicException: Key does not exist"

```
            var identityServiceBuild = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.KeyManagement.Enabled = false;
            });

            string keyVaultName = "mykeyvault";
            var kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

            var keyClient = new KeyClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var keyResponse = keyClient.GetKey("devidentityserver");

            RSA rsa = keyResponse.Value.Key.ToRSA();
            key = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa) { KeyId = keyResponse.Value.Properties.Version };

           identityServiceBuild.AddSigningCredential(key, IdentityServerConstants.RsaSigningAlgorithm.RS256);
```

Here is more of the stack trace if that helps:

```
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Key does not exist.
   at Internal.Cryptography.CngCommon.SignHash(SafeNCryptKeyHandle keyHandle, ReadOnlySpan`1 hash, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void* pPaddingInfo, Int32 estimatedSize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.SignHash(Byte[] hash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.Sign(Byte[] input)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.CreateTokenPrivate(JObject payload, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials, String compressionAlgorithm, IDictionary`2 additionalHeaderClaims, String tokenType)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.CreateToken(String payload, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, IDictionary`2 additionalHeaderClaims)
   at Duende.IdentityServer.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(Token token, String payload, Dictionary`2 headerElements) in /_/src/IdentityServer/Services/Default/DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 138
```

Is it because it's expecting the key to be persisted as a row in the "Keys" SQL table? I'm thinking not because I've disabled key management via KeyManagement.Enabled = false?

Help!

Comment: The azure key vault key is definitely retrieved down to my local machine successfully and code executes past successfully "AddSigningCredential".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
var keyResponse = keyClient.GetKey("devidentityserver");
```

Only will return the public key from KeyVault, to get the private key, you need to get it as a secret. (yes, its odd).

This is the code I use in my setup to get the key from keyvault:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Load a certificate (with private key) from Azure Key Vault
        ///
        /// Getting a certificate with private key is a bit of a pain, but the code below solves it.
        /// 
        /// Get the private key for Key Vault certificate
        /// https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert
        /// 
        /// See also these GitHub issues: 
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12742
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12083
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(IConfiguration config, string certificateName)
        {
            string vaultUrl = config["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
            string clientId = config["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
            string tenantId = config["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
            string secret = config["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

            Console.WriteLine($"Loading certificate '{certificateName}' from Azure Key Vault");

            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
            var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);

            var cert = GetCertificateAsync(certClient, secretClient, certificateName);

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate loaded");
            return cert;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to get a certificate
        /// 
        /// Source https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert/blob/master/Program.cs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="certificateClient"></param>
        /// <param name="secretClient"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient,
                                                                SecretClient secretClient,
                                                                string certificateName)
        {

            KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);

            // Return a certificate with only the public key if the private key is not exportable.
            if (certificate.Policy?.Exportable != true)
            {
                return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);
            }

            // Parse the secret ID and version to retrieve the private key.
            string[] segments = certificate.SecretId.AbsolutePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (segments.Length != 3)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Number of segments is incorrect: {segments.Length}, URI: {certificate.SecretId}");
            }

            string secretName = segments[1];
            string secretVersion = segments[2];

            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName, secretVersion);

            // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
            // .NET 5.0 preview introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
            if ("application/x-pkcs12".Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
                return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException($"Only PKCS#12 is supported. Found Content-Type: {secret.Properties.ContentType}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'm retrieving a key from Azure Key Vault but interpreting or treating it like a secret from Azure Key Vault? Is that right?

Comment: It worked @Tore but I needed to set up and use a certificate in Azure key vault... as opposed to just using an RSA Key like the Duende documentation would have you believe?

Comment: I'm guessing this from the appsettings.json which was used for identity server 4 can be gotten rid of?

"IdentityServer": { "Key": { "Type": "Store", "Name": "CN=myproduct.com.au", "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser", "StoreName": "My" } },

Comment: You can add normal RSA keys in Azure, perhaps wrapped in a "certificate". Back when I dealt with it, I placed my RSA key inside a certificate and also a PKCE12 file. But I am sure there's perhaps better ways to do it.  The certificate it self is not important, its just a data-container for the key. 

Also, think you can use the key directly in AKV, but you need to get the private key as a secret.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it hlped.